# arabic words splitted into two parts on Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arabic

arabic words are splitted into two parts on HTML/Javascript, so word like "الفقير" is displayed on two lines like "ير" "الفق" each part on seperated line. And this is happening for some characters/words and others are displayed correctly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In my HTML I set the meta charset to utf-8 like this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Please any help to fixe this ?

Comment: Could you add a **runnable** [mcve] to your question using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) please? It will make it much easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of this issue.
This is due to the font I was using. So it's not related to javascript or HTML.